# Transform excel file with multiple date columns in Power Query

Tags: datetime, powerbi, transform, powerquery, tabular

I have a table in excel, that I need to import into my data model i Power BI. I need to be able to slice and dice the dates (day, week, month, year). But I am not sure how to transform this data best.

Would it best to summarize it across the different dimensions (name, contract, sub-contract)?

The raw format looks like this in my excel spreadsheet:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend unpivoting the date columns into a single date column.

Slicing and dicing pivot tables works much better on tall tables rather than wide tables.

Comment: I did not know this feature. Works like a charm. Thanks Alexis. To explain to others, the solution is to 'unpivot' the table by selecting columns (Name, Contract and Project) and right-click and choose "Unpivot other columns". This gives the desired result.